# Which DNS record should I use to redirect request to sub domain to main domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I created a DNS record in co.cc to make it point to x10hosting account. So I have like `<mydomain>.co.cc  - A - <x10 ip>`

Its working properly. Now problem is I have already mentioned name like `blog.<mydomain>.co.cc` in my previous resumes which I cannot change. So is it possible to redirect sub-domain request to main domain using DNS record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **add a CNAME, but it would not suffice**.

This way you only tell browsers that the IP of your blog is the same as the one pointed by your domain DNS record:

```
blog.dom.tld -> dom.tld -> <your.ip>
```

If your HTTP server does not implements Vhosts (and I suppose it **does** as you are in a shared server :), you would had done.

As your server is a Vhost, **you have to instruct it to properly handle both blog.dom.tld and dom.tld** as the same vhost. You can achieve this behavior using **`ServerAlias` apache directive**, for example

EDIT:

don't know your host, but from [their forum](http://forums.x10hosting.com/programming-help/74807-how-add-sub-domain-000-default-file.html#post421288) it seems you can login and do it by hand.

Comment: Where can I make those settings , I have control panel 11 on http://x10hosting.com

Comment: You need to add a subdomain on the control panel, if they'll let you do that.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked :)  ... But why www was working using CNAME record? OR is it by default provided by x10hosting ?

Comment: I suppose the default env of x10 already handle in the same vhost both domain and www.domain, as it is quite usual that the are the same :)

Comment: -1 because adding the CNAME has side-effects (aliasing blog.mydomain.example to mydomain.example: that will inherit  MX, NS etc records). Good practice is to add address records (A and AAAA).

Comment: Side effects that are normal.. if they are really the same it is obvious they should have the same MX and so on .. an alias is a "link" to something, not a "fake" or "ghost" of a real think. I do not agree, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

as already said, dns do not do redirection.

dns only resolving name to ip.

if you're using apache server, 
just point the domain to your server ip and you can use .htaccess for redirection.

Comment: Correct. Mod_rewrite in your Apache config or .htaccess will allow very powerful redirection and URL rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

DNS doesn't really do redirection like this.  Usually you have to point both domains at a web server setup virtual hosts for both domains, and create a rule in in the virtual host to send a redirect.

If you look around there are free/cheap services (e.g. [dyndns](http://www.dyndns.com/support/kb/webhops_redirections.html)) that will do the redirection for you.  Basically you point the name that you want redirected at them, then tell them what URL to redirect too.

Comment: Actually I did tried pointing "www" CNAME record to main domain which works...but similar settings for "blog" does not work ?

Comment: my answer explains why, and how you can do it work